# JQuery going through a set of UL and dynamically set ids incremently on each one

Tags: jquery, dom, attributes, loops

I have an unordered list which contains several items called 'oListItems' the UL has a class but no id.

The class OuteroListItems contains many of oListitems

```
 oList.AppendFormat("<ul class='OuteroListItems'>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<ul class='oListItems'>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.sName + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.eName + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.SDate + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("<li>" + s.EDate + "</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("</ul>");
            oList.AppendFormat("</li>");
            oList.AppendFormat("</ul>");
```

I want for each .oListItem class that gets retrieved, add dynamically an id to it.

```
 var o = $(".oListItem");

    $.each(o, function (){

      var f = $(this).attr("id", 'listItem' + i);

        i++;
    });
```

wasent sure on the approach, this is what I have so far?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this use [`.each()`](http://api.jquery.com/each/) (off the element collection), note that ID cannot start with a number:

```
$('.oListItems').each(function(i) {
  $(this).attr('id', 'listItem' + i);
});
```

The [`.each()` function gets 2 parameters](http://api.jquery.com/each/), `(index, element)`, you just need the first, in this case `i` is the index (zero-based) of the current `.oListItem` you're on.

Comment: say I wanted to see the id after this, i tried this 
var show = $("#prefix1").text();
            alert(show);

but didnt work, not sure if thats how i then retrieve the id?

Comment: @Calibre - I left out an `s` on `oListItems`, fixed now, remember the index is 0 based, the first one will be `$("#listItem0")`, you can see an example here: http://jsfiddle.net/t3fAb/

Answer (score 0):

What you have looks fine to me except that you want to declare and initialize `i` somewhere. But it can be simpler. You can use the index jQuery passes into the `$.each` callback, and just assign directly to the `id` property on the given element rather than constructing a jQuery object around it just so you can set the attribute via `attr`. E.g.:

```
$.each(o, function(index) {

    this.id = 'listItem' + index;

});
```

But if you want to construct the jQuery object around each element for other reasons, :

```
$.each(o, function(index) {

    $(this).attr("id", 'listItem' + index);

});
```

(Also no need to declare and use that variable `f` if you don't use it, so I left it out of the above.)